# Does every positive power of $7$ contain $2$ in their ternary representation?

Tags: combinatorial-number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

Does every positive power of $7$ contain $2$ in their ternary representation? I.e. Determine whether there exists a finite subset of non-negative integers $\{a_1 < \dots < a_n \}$ and a positive integer $b$ such that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n 3^{a_i} = 7^b.
$$

I've done a little bit of computation and found that if there are no solutions for $a_i$ if $b < 5000$. So I feel like there is no solution in general and I've had some unsuccessful attempts at proving it. I began by looking at the last few digits of the termary representation of $7^n$, effectively looking at the $7^n \  \textrm{mod } 3^k $ for certain values of $k$. With this I can show is that $7^{3n}$ always contains a $2$. But I realised that for any fixed $k$ there exists $n$ such that $7^n \equiv 1 \  \textrm{mod } 3^k$ since $7$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/ 3^k\mathbb{Z}$. I've also had a look through the computations at the first first few digits of the ternary representation of $7^n$ but I haven't seen any repeating patterms. As a follow up question: Does there exists $k$ such that for all $n$ there is always a $2$ within the first $k$ significant digits of $7^n$?

If anyone knows any results related to this question, I would also be interested to hear about those.

Comment: The answer to the follow up question is "no": for any sequence of $k$ ternary digits, there is an $n$ so that $7^n$ in base 3 has those first $k$ significant digits. That's because $\log_37$ is irrational, so the fractional parts of its multiples are dense in $[0,1]$. I've continued your calculations (search for a power without digit 2), it's beyond exponent 277000 and running, but that doesn't prove anything, naturally.